# Sqlmap - Continuing a large query

Tags: sqlmap

I'm going to admit I'm not a sqlmap expert, hoping the community can help me learn something.

> sqlmap -u "https://www.domain.com/page.php?id=1" --batch -D database_name -T table_name --dump -C "[column list]"

- I ran the above sqlmap command on a very large database. Let's say I ran the query on April 1, 2022.
- It took approx. 1 second to retrieve each record in the database (this is relevant in a later bullet point).
- It took ~7 days to dump the entire database. However, there are no records dumped that are later than April 1, 2022 (the date I started the dump). I know there are records between April 1, 2022 and April 7, but the same sqlmap command will not dump them.

I thought I could continue the dump by running a query similar to the following (where "100000" is the last id retrieved in the original dump).

> sqlmap -u "https://www.domain.com/page.php?id=1" --batch -D database_name -sql-query="select [column list] FROM table_name WHERE id > 100000"

- This resulted in a query that ran for maybe 30 seconds (instead of the 1 sec per row I experienced with the original command).
- The console displayed hundreds of rows of data (although still not all of them, but definitely displayed records beyond my original dump).
- I can't find the dumped data anywhere. I looked in the folder that sqlmap indicates the dumped data was saved to and I don't see anything (the original dump saved CSV files).

I must be doing something wrong here. My goal is to dump the entire database. How can I use the original query (which was slow, but working well) to dump data beyond the date that I originally ran the command?

Happy to answer any follow-up questions needed to get to an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the switch

> --fresh-queries

although you have to add

> WHERE id > 100000

or whatever the last ID you were able to dump was.

Also the saved data and dump is normally in the *.sqlmap/output/* folder. If it's not there, then you may have started sqlmap with sudo or another user.
Just take a  look in the */root/.sqlmap/output* and  */home/[user]/.sqlmap/output/* folder

Comment: I think that did it. 

sqlmap -u "https://www.domain.com/page.php?id=1" --batch -D database_name -T table_name --dump -C "[column list]" --where "id > 100000" --fresh-queries